# Probability RV is min among several iid RVs

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, scipy

This question is inspired by [this programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77082592/calculate-probability-that-normal-distribution-sample-is-smallest-in-group-polar/77084753?noredirect=1#comment135898519_77084753).

Suppose I have 3 RVs which are independent.

$$X \sim N(25.5, 2.5)$$

$$Y \sim N(25.2, 3.5)$$

$$Z \sim N(24.9, 1.7)$$

I want to know what is the probability that X is the minimum of the three. My first inclination was that is $P(X<Y) * P(X<Z)$ or $P(X-Y<0) * P(X-Z<0)$

which would be
$$\Phi\Big(\frac{0-(25.5-25.2)}{\sqrt{2.5^2+3.5^2}}\Big)*\Phi\Big(\frac{0-(25.5-24.9)}{\sqrt{2.5^2+1.7^2}}\Big)\approx 0.47219 * 0.421341\approx0.1986$$

Now I do the same for Y and Z and get, respectively, 0.24768 and 0.30711.

but that's wrong as I'm not taking into account that if X<Y then X<Z isn't independent. **Can this be done without simulation with python scipy?**

If I do

```
import scipy.integrate as spi
import scipy.stats as sps
def fX(x):
    return sps.norm(x, loc=25.5, scale=2.5)
spi.quad(fX, 0, 25.5)
```

then I get the same (to an approximation) thing as using the cdf

```
sps.norm(loc=25.5, scale=2.5).cdf(25.5)
```

I think I need to *somehow* combine the functions and integrate them but I'm not sure if this is the best route anyway or if it's even possible or more feasible than a simulation.

As an aside, I found [this](https://www.untruth.org/%7Ejosh/math/normal-min.pdf) which has some Mathematica code at the end which, I think, does what I'm looking to do but I couldn't figure out how to make it in scipy.

Comment: Note that the events $X<Y$ and $X<Z$ are not independent, since if $Y < Z$ and $X<Y$, then $X<Z$. What you are trying to compute is $\Pr(X < \min(Y,Z))$.